# MongoDb and NodeJs // Store data from DB to variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

UPDATE: After first answerI realized that should clarify. I need to retrieve data from 2 different documents from db and compare them. So I was thinking about solution and seems to find it.

*My question was:*

I'm new in NodeJs and MongoDb and I'm stuck trying to set data received from mongoDb to variable:

```
let variableToStoreData1;
let variableToStoreData2;

db.collection('costs').find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
   console.log('result', result[0].user.last_name);
   variableToStoreData1 = result;
});

db.collection('messages').find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
   console.log('result', result[0].user.last_name);
   variableToStoreData2 = result;
});

console.log(variableToStoreData1) // undefined
console.log(variableToStoreData2) // undefined
```

*My solution*
    let variableToStoreData1;
    let variableToStoreData2;

```
db.collection('costs').find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
  console.log('result', result[0].user.last_name);
  variableToStoreData1 = result;
});

db.collection('messages').find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
 console.log('result', result[0].user.last_name);
 variableToStoreData2 = result;
 callback();
});

function callback () {
  console.log(variableToStoreData1) // now it's defined
  console.log(variableToStoreData2) // now it's defined
}
```

Comment: So when you console.log(result) it is there. What's the problem then?

Comment: @NikolaAndreev Just updated my code. So if you see `variableToStoreData` are undefined but I need it to store result there

Answer (score 0):

That's because you print the variable before you set it. The `variableToStoreData` is `undefined` when you print it and you set it a few millisecond later when the response from `db.find` arrive.

```
let variableToStoreData;

db.collection('costs').find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
   console.log('result', result[0].user.last_name);
   variableToStoreData = result;
   callback()
});

function callback() {
   console.log(variableToStoreData) // now it's not undefined
}
```